# Fully Connected Layer with numbers

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am having some trouble understanding how to implement a fully connected layer. Can someone share an example with real values?

Ex. Flattening the input, multiplying by the weights, adding the bias, etc.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow does most of the low-level stuff for you.

Have a look at one of the getting started tutorials where there are complete examples in just a few lines of code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

link: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials